# Does Compiling Java to Native Code with -Xcomp Always Enhance Performance?

Tags: java, c, jvm, jit

In an [Oracle post](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/the-best-hotspot-jvm-options-and-switches-for-java-11-through-java-17), it's mentioned that C2 compiles hotspots into efficient native code, storing it in the code cache. A [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369791/java-vm-tuning-xbatch-and-xcomp) pointed out that using `-Xcomp` compiles all code into native code, but this might reduce overall performance.

This leaves me puzzled. Wouldn't running entirely on native code be the most efficient? Even if, as some comments suggest, the 'cold' native code is bulkier than compact bytecode (which generally isn't the case, as [this post](https://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-byte-code-and-machine-code-in-java#:%7E:text=Byte%20code%20and%20machine%20code%20are%20two%20important%20terms%20used,executed%20by%20the%20computer%27s%20processor.) indicates), shouldn't it still be viable, considering that C/C++ operates exclusively with native code?

Looking forward to a detailed explanation with appreciation

Comment: [The accepted answer to the post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439450/8681) actually explains the reason very well. The JVM uses those first few executions to *optimize* the compiled code, and it couldn't do that if you forced a compile at startup.

Comment: [it would cost more time to compile them than the amortized
time saved by running them in compiled mode](https://answers.ycrash.io/question/what-is-java-forced-compilation-mode--xcomp?q=652)

Comment: @teapot418: That's not a very good reason to remove the ability to request that behaviour at all.  Perhaps some use-cases and real-time guarantees for the first request after starting, without having to simulate a bunch of calls to important functions first.  (Just one or two calls to get things warmed up, maybe, since even ahead-of-time compiled programs have warm-up effects, and there's the CPU.)

Comment: What does make sense is that compiling without profiling data from the early runs is a new mode that the JVM wouldn't have to support if the option were removed.  e.g. it has to guess about branch takenness like an AoT compiler.  (Or just make simplistic assumptions: if the JITed asm really tends to be a lot worse than when JITing after some training runs, then it makes sense to at least deprecate the option so people aren't fooled by the performance numbers they see from it.)

Comment: Compiling byte code to native code may not always improve performance. For infrequently-used code a smallish interpreter and concise byte code may fit better into CPU caches than oodles of cold native code.

Comment: @teapot418: Interesting point that might be true if the interpreter is fast enough vs. code-fetch bandwidth (or I-cache miss latency after hard-to-predict jumps).  The OP is kind of asking the wrong question about whether that's faster or not; deprecation is about the option not being recommended for *any* use case, e.g. because it no longer works as designed after changes to the internals don't properly support it, so maybe it makes asm that's not like normal JIT would.  The question of whether it's always faster would be relevant for whether it should be on by default, not deprecation.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you and I have edited post according to comments above. Wish you think it's appropriate now and can share further insight.

Comment: The accepted answer you linked on [Java VM tuning - Xbatch and -Xcomp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439450) explains some reasons why it's not always faster: compiling without the profiling information from the early runs can lead to worse asm.  Speculatively treating invariants as constants can simplify the asm a lot.  As for relative size of Java bytecode vs. x86-64 machine code, I don't know what's typical.  Hotspot (the JVM you're talking about) does sometimes unroll loops, but hopefully wouldn't do that without profiling info.

Comment: @PeterCordes 'Speculatively treating invariants as constants can simplify the asm a lot.' This sounds like a solid answer to me, and it is not clear from the linked post which just described in a general way without detail. Could you share this line with a new answer? I believe it's valuable for Java Programmers who care performance but not very familiar with asm procedure.

Comment: Compiling only pays off if executing the compiled is faster than interpreting the code (which is not always given) *and* this gain multiplied with the number of executions of the code is higher than the time needed to compile the code. In other words, code executed only a few times or even only once, like initialization code, is very unlikely to benefit from JIT compilation, even if we assume the compilation to produce perfectly optimized results.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all insight from above comments, the answer is no, because of the potential of the JIT compiler which is one form of [dynamic compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_compilation).

Dynamic compilation makes it possible to utilize runtime information generating performant native code.

Hope this post helps java programmers get a better understand of JIT copmiler.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?