# Creating a new WebDriver causes StackOverflowError

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm just trying to get setup and have the ability to run the [example](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example) from Selenium's website. However I've narrowed it down to the FirefoxDriver constructor causing a StackOverflowError. I get the same behavior with InternetExplorerDriver, but not HtmlUnitDriver.

The following code

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebDriverTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

Produces the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:937)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
  at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
  at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
  at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
  at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
  at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
  at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
  at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
  at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
  at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1539)
  at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:939)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
  :
  :
```

I'm using selenium-java-2.22.0 and the json jar that was packaged with the download (which is json-20080701.jar)

Also of note, when running the new FirefoxDriver, Firefox does launch and you see a new tab page. With InternetExplorerDriver, no window opens, but it produces the same stacktrace with JSONObject looping infinitely. I'm running Firefox 12.0 and IE9 on Windows 7.

Comment: Wow. Just as a debugging tool, try running it with `-Xss1m` or more (generally default is 512 kB for 32-bit JVMs) to see whether the recursion is really infinite. What is your Java JDK and/or JRE version? Are you absolutely sure there are no conflicting jars in the project's classpath?

Comment: I had already added the parameter `-Xms1024m`. Per your suggestion, I just wiped the folder containing my dependencies, removed all the dependency entries from my ivy.xml file except for selenium and its dependencies then repulled my dependencies. Firefox now works and I get a different error from IE. So now I get to have fun determining which dependencies are conflicting. If you add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Welcome to [JAR hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_hell#JAR_hell)

Some of the JAR files in your classpath are conflicting with Selenium dependencies. It is kinda strange that it happened even though you are using Ivy. One of your dependencies most likely includes the conflicting classes inside its jar file - or your dependencies need two different versions of the same library.

Anyway, for future user reading this - use some dependency manager to do the hard work with jars for you. Don't try to maintain your libraries manually if you have more that 10 projects with dependencies - you'll most likely screw it up soon. [This is quite a reasonable read on dependency solutions, follow some of the links there, don't be lazy.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571616/is-platform-enforced-versioning-mechanism-most-sorely-needed-feature-of-java) Dependency managers take some time to master, they are a world for themselves. But they help a lot.

Don't use multiple versions of the same library. And if you use multiple libraries from which two use a different version of the same thing ... good luck to you!

Other than that ... our only hope is [Java Module System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Module_System) which will be introduced in <del>Java 8</del> Java 9.

Comment: ps: the cause of the problem and the reason that Ivy was unable to catch the issue and evict the older jar is because we have another project that was being pulled in that has an old version of [pubnub](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/java) as a dependency. Turns out that pubnub essentially just took all the org.json code and put it in their project. Then, since pubnub appeared in the classpath before the org.json that was declared as a dependency of selenium, it got pulled by the WebDriver constructor. I suspect there is a bug in that older version of the org.json library.

Comment: Sometimes it's strange to me that Sun allowed for this great issue to appear when their engineers usually think about every little hole. I'm so looking forward to Java 8.

Comment: FTR, I just ran into this with Riak 1.0.5 + Selenium in my classpath. Turns out the Riak client includes org.json in the jar.

Answer (score 1):

We are hitting this as well, and I can confirm that you encounter this if your test project has org.json classes of other/older versions than the ones WebDriver needs (20080701) somewhere on its classpath.

PS: FTR I've opened http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4123 "by mistake", so just to clarify that this is NOT A WEBDRIVER ISSUE.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your json library on your class path with the one comes with selenium which locats in /Selenium-x.xx/lib/json-20080701.jar